# Firebase Cloud Firestore Snapshot listen too fast

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

Hi I'm creating an app in React-Native and Invertase RN-Firebase. I'm using firestore for the first time for my new project. I notice the realtime update 'Snapshot' the behavior seems to listen too fast. I'm worried that this will kill my budget for the billing.

Form my previous experience with Firebase Realtime-Database the update/listening from snapshot was not so fast and it check ever other 4 to 10 seconds which in FIrestore it  listening per millisecond.

let me know if there is a way to slow down the Listening of snapshot for Cloud firestore.

thanks,

Comment: The underlying protocols used almost guarantee that the data transfer (after the initial establishing of the connection) will be faster with Realtime Database than with Cloud Firestore. But it's hard to say how to improve what you are experiencing without seeing a [minimal self-contained example that reproduces the performance problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and preferably some concrete measurements of the performance on your system.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to limit or configure how often the triggered listeners receive data - in theory any changes should be sent to your app almost immediately, but in practice there's some latency in the process... resulting in the 4-10 seconds you observed elsewhere. Firestore is apparently better optimized since you are not seeing that much delay.

If you are concerned about budget or billing, the best advice I can give you is to review the official [Optimization Suggestions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize). Those are for the RTDB, not Firestore, but they're still useful suggestions.

Note that it doesn't count as a billable "read" unless the data is changing, and unless your data is changing near-constantly, you shouldn't have to worry about billing... Check out the [Firestore pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) which includes this explanatory paragraph regarding billing for listeners:

> Listening to query results
>
> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the
>   results of a query and get realtime updates when the query results
>   change.
>
> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
>   each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are
>   also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
>   because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is
>   deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
>   example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
>   if you had issued a brand-new query.